# SQL Trigger creation

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to create a trigger based on 2 tables storing data.

The first tables attributes are id, trait1, trait2, trait3, trait4, trait5. 
The second tables attiributes are id, num_submitted, sum_trait1, sum_trait2, sum_trait3, sum_trait4.

When something is added to the first table, the trigger needs to increment the num_submitted, and add the values of each of the traits to their respective sums.

Below is what I have currently but it compiles with errors and does not execute. I would greatly appreciate any help on this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER submit_trigger    
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON Surveydata    
FOR EACH ROW WHEN (surveys.survey_id = inserted.survey_id)    
BEGIN    
UPDATE surveys    
SET surveys.numSubmitted= surveydata.numSubq1mitted++, surveys.sum_q1=    
(surveys.sum_q1+new.q1),
        surveys.sum_q2= (surveys.sum_q2+new.q2), surveys.sum_q3= (surveys.sum_q3+new.q3),
        surveys.sum_q4= (surveys.sum_q4+new.q4)    
    WHERE (surveys.survey_id = new.survey_id)    
END;
```

Comment: Please add the errors you're getting on compile

Comment: SQL Statement ignored on line 2 
Missing expression on line 3
Encountered "end of file" on line 7

But I think these are stemming from it being built wrong.

Comment: Yes it is Oracle... Working with sqlplus via putty

Comment: There is no `inserted` in Oracle. And you cannot reference other tables in the `WHEN` condition of a trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following may help:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER submit_trigger    
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON Surveydata    
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
  UPDATE surveys s
    SET s.numSubmitted = :new.numSubmitted + 1,
        s.sum_q1 = surveys.sum_q1 + :new.q1,
        s.sum_q2 = surveys.sum_q2 + :new.q2,
        s.sum_q3 = surveys.sum_q3 + :new.q3,
        s.sum_q4 = surveys.sum_q4 + :new.q4
    WHERE s.survey_id = :new.survey_id;
END;
```

Share and enjoy.